# Boost geometry: composing polygons from many points

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm coding a physical simulation and after having done the dynamical parts I would like to use some geometric tools to analyze my system. These interesting parts are several clusters of points forming different closed loops (or polygons). The way I parameterized makes it really difficult (at least for me) to separate these loops one from each other. I'm pretty confident about using the boost geometry library for the geometric manipulation of this data, and that's why I'm thinking about sending all these points forming polygons in one boost geometry object (or vector of points simply) and I'm looking for a way of separating them after that using the fact that points too far apart can't be part of the same polygon and then forming several polygons I will manipulate separately.

I haven't manipulated much of boost geometry so far, and I don't know how easy/difficult it can be to implement something like that within it. Are there some default functions that could be of good use in these tasks.

I'm giving you a picture of what I'd like my program to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can triangulate the points and remove the longest edges. I use it for my concave hull algorithm: http://www.phpdevpad.de/geofence.